# как сделать так ,чтобы пользователь мог удалять и редактировать записи

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp7
{
 struct Worker
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Incident { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
    public Worker(string N, int A, string E, int P) { Name = N; Age = A; 
        Incident = E; Priority = P; }
    public string ToString() { return $"{Name,10} {Age,10} {Incident,10} {Priority,10}"; }
}
struct Rep
{
    Worker[] db;
    int index;
    public Rep(int count) { db = new Worker[count]; index = 0; }
    public void Add(Worker worker) { db[index++] = worker; }
    public void Print() { for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) { Console.WriteLine(db[i].ToString()); } }

}
class Program
{
    static Worker GetWorker()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Введите Name: ");
        var name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Введите Age: ");
        var age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Введите Event: ");
        var incident = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Введите Priority : "); 
        var priority = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        return new Worker(name, age, incident, priority);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var rep = new Rep(10);
        var w = GetWorker(); rep.Add(w);
        //w = GetWorker(); rep.Add(w);
        //w = GetWorker(); rep.Add(w);

        rep.Print();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```

Это ежедневник ,смог сделать только чтобы пользователь 
мог добавлять записи, как сделать так ,чтобы пользователь 
мог удалять и редактировать  записи

Comment: а какие у вас проблемы с этим? Что именно не получается?

Comment: А зачем делать отдельный класс Rep, чем вам не угодил List<Worker>, который поддерживает Add, Insert, Delete и многое другое?

Comment: @KuzCode, я бы ещё спросил зачем называть структуру Rep, а не Repository? То есть от этого сокращения получена какая-то выгода? Зачем делать в данном случае структуру, а не класс?

Answer (score 1):

Вот примерно как это должно выглядеть. И нужно было подробнее написать, что подразумевается под редактированием.

Не пиши код в одну строку, читать тяжело такое.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleAppRep
{
    public class Worker
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Age { get; set; }

        public string Incident { get; set; }

        public int Priority { get; set; }

        public Worker(string name, int age, string incident, int priority)
        {
            Name = name;
            Age = age;
            Incident = incident;
            Priority = priority;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{Name,10} {Age,10} {Incident,10} {Priority,10}";
        }
    }

    public class Repository
    {
        private readonly List<Worker> _db;

        public Repository(int count)
        {
            _db = new List<Worker>(count);
        }

        public void Add(Worker worker)
        {
            if (worker == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(worker));
            }

            _db.Add(worker);
        }

        public void RemoveAt(int index)
        {
            _db.RemoveAt(index);
        }

        public bool Remove(Worker worker)
        {
            if (worker == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(worker));
            }

            return _db.Remove(worker);
        }

        public IEnumerable<Worker> EnumerateWorkers()
        {
            foreach (var worker in _db)
            {
                yield return worker;
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        #region Entry point

        private static Program _program;

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            _program = new Program();
            _program.Run(args);
        }

        #endregion

        private Worker GetWorker(int number)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Worker " + number);
            string name = GetUserInputAsString("Введите Name: ");
            int age = GetUserInputAsInt32("Введите Age: ");
            string incident = GetUserInputAsString("Введите Event: ");
            int priority = GetUserInputAsInt32("Введите Priority: ");

            return new Worker(name, age, incident, priority);
        }

        private string GetUserInputAsString(string message)
        {
            string input;
            do
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(message);
                }
                input = Console.ReadLine();

            } while (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input));

            return input;
        }

        private int GetUserInputAsInt32(string message)
        {
            int result;
            string input;
            do
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(message);
                }

                input = Console.ReadLine();

            } while (!int.TryParse(input, out result));

            return result;
        }

        private void Print(IEnumerable<Worker> workers)
        {
            foreach (var worker in workers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(worker.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void Run(string[] args)
        {
            var repo = new Repository(10);
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                repo.Add(GetWorker(i + 1));
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Список: ");
            Print(repo.EnumerateWorkers());
            repo.RemoveAt(1);
            Console.WriteLine("После удаления: ");
            Print(repo.EnumerateWorkers());

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь

Comment: А под редактирование я имел ввиду то ,что бы пользователь мог изменять свои записи